# How to retrieve all post and verify if user liked the post with an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like know how to retrieve all post and verify which one I liked with a dynamic UserId

**the query that I tried is :**

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.content,
    posts.user_id,
    users.pseudo,
    posts.score,
    posts_score.user_id as 'liked'
FROM
    posts
    INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
    LEFT JOIN posts_score ON posts_score.posts_id = posts.id
ORDER BY
    posts.date DESC
LIMIT
    100
```

| id | content | user_id | pseudo | score | liked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Hhhkdk | 83 | Bxbbxnx | 0 | 83 |
| 2 | Heyy | 83 | Bxbbxnx | 1 | 68 |
| 1 | Hello | 68 | Test | 0 | 68 |
| 1 | Hello | 68 | Test | 0 | 83 |

I think that I should introduce the ID : 68 in the request but I don't know how

**Two issue here:**

1. Don't want see Double post ( like Hello )
2. I only want see results with the userId 68 and If I didn't liked one of these post, I would like see null on Liked column.

I don't want to see 83 in liked column, only 68 OR null if I didn't liked the post.

**I would like this**

| id | content | user_id | pseudo | score | liked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Hhhkdk | 83 | Bxbbxnx | 0 | NULL |
| 2 | Heyy | 83 | Bxbbxnx | 1 | 68 |
| 1 | Hello | 68 | Test | 0 | 68 |

Need your help friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
SELECT distinct
    posts.id,
    posts.content,
    posts.user_id,
    users.pseudo,
    posts.score,
    posts_score.user_id as 'liked'
FROM
    posts
INNER JOIN users 
   ON posts.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN posts_score 
   ON posts_score.posts_id = posts.id
   AND posts_score.user_id = 68
ORDER BY
    posts.date DESC
LIMIT  100
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a beast. You made my day, thanks thanks thanks